# html post on the site

Tags: css, html

New to html I have decided to create a html blog using html5 and css(just for the background) and can't seem to get the posted blog made by the user post to the webpage. Any help will be appreciated and here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Blog centre</title>
</head>

<style>
body{background-color: darkgrey;}
</style>

<body>

<h1>Blog centre</h1>

<p>
Post your blog here:
</p>

<form method="post" name="blog form" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
<table width="550" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td width="100">Name *</td>
<td><input name="blogname" type="text" size="30" maxlength="10"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Blog: *</td>
<td><textarea name="blogmessage" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="10000"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="blog form" type="submit" value="Post blog" onClick="return che$
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
<br/>

<br/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your html syntax:

...

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form(this);">
<table width="550" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td width="100">Name *</td>
<td><input name="blogname" type="text" size="30" maxlength="10"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Blog: *</td>
<td><textarea name="blogmessage" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="10000"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="blog_form" type="submit" value="Post blog"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I believe this will crash also `onsubmit="return validate_form(this)"` , because I can't see anything any include of JS resource. You don't have any definition of this function **validate_form( el )** , so ... you can remove "onsubmit" attribute of your FORM tag ( only if you don't need it )

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you will need some form of "backend" to handle persisting the blogpost? Do you have a database at all?

Comment: I changed this `<td><input name="blog form" type="submit" value="Post blog" onClick="return che$` to `<td><input name="blog_form" type="submit" value="Post blog"></td>` Your submit button has no end and it's parent </td> was also missing ...

Answer (score 0):

HTML pages, by default, cannot process input. It's a language made for marking elements so that your browser can display them properly. For example `<h1>` gives you a big header and `<p></p>` gives you a new paragraph in between. It's best compared with a Word document where you can look under the hood.

You basically made a form appear. That's it. Your HTML will offer no functionality by itself.

If you want to work with user generated input, you can use javascript or PHP (and many other tools, but those are the most common starting points). Look for a tutorial on 'How to code a blog' and you will get a better understanding of what I'm talking about.